# Css floats between image and text

Tags: css

I have this situation and i want to set the text in the right side but i dont want to cross the red line [image]

The image have float:left; + margin-right and the div with content have set a with.

How to make text stat in the right side?

Comment: You can simply use `text-align: right` but for the sake of clarification please post your real code examples.

Comment: It depends on wether you know what size the image will be. If its a fixed size you can just pad the text and absolutely position the image. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/h7dupnae/

Comment: Really? `text-align: right`? `position: absolute`? If I could downvote comments...

Comment: wrap the text and image in `div`s, and then float them

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, applying `overflow: hidden` to your right-hand column will give you the effect you desire:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Banh mi fanny pack selfies disrupt. Small batch art party umami chia bicycle rights flannel fingerstache, wolf single-origin coffee mustache dreamcatcher squid. Odd Future drinking vinegar Echo Park yr. Bicycle rights stumptown PBR, fashion axe put a bird on it raw denim photo booth sriracha synth. Pitchfork chambray next level, photo booth PBR hoodie VHS Blue Bottle squid church-key keytar meh bespoke organic master cleanse. Tousled Williamsburg synth normcore fap. Roof party Thundercats tofu, Cosby sweater Tonx Banksy chambray direct trade Pitchfork disrupt ethical kitsch keffiyeh mlkshk synth.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { float: left;  margin-right: 10px; }
.content { overflow: hidden; }
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1p981db/

With an `overflow` other than `visible`, a new box-context is created, which prevents boxes from overlapping. This means that your floated container and your content container will keep to themselves, rather than wrapping around one another.